# PHP Simple DOM Parser Parse Current PHP Page

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I am using the PHP Simple DOM parser to extract all of the image sources on a given page like so:

```
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com/');

// Retrieve all images and print their SRCs
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

Instead of using Google.com, I wish to use a page on Wordpress's admin (backend) area. These pages are PHP pages, not HTML (but the page has standard HTML throughout).  How would I use the current page as the `$html` variable? PHP newbie over here.

Comment: If you use file_get_html using a URL as you show above you'd be getting the parsed php document, which is the same for your purposes as using a .html file. However, you likely won't be able to access a page in the admin panel from PHP because it probably requires you to be logged in with a cookie in order to access.

Comment: yes, the assumption is the user would be logged in, so that is OK. Yes, the PHP is already parsed, so it is an HTML page. I cant use file_get_html effectively because the URL will be dynamically generated. This needs to work on all pages that load this php script.

Comment: the url would be like this (with id numbers varying):  http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_entries&view=entry&id=4&lid=11&filter=&paged=1&pos=0

Comment: Unfortunately, your login in the browser isn't going to carry over to the server side, so you can't use a script like this.

You might consider trying to find these image sources via some other means, such as directly querying the database.

Comment: This script would be placed in a function that is accessed by a certain wordpress admin page. I dont see why this wouldnt work. I can get it to work with regex but I do not want to parse HTML via regex.

Comment: Gotcha. Then the problem becomes that you're going to try to access a page which, prior to rendering will try to access the same page which, prior to rendering will try to access the same page which, prior to rendering will try to access the same page which...

If you are truly desperate and you're certain this is the only way to do it, is to pass an additional parameter in the url which would tell your function to skip the img strip, and go straight to rendering so you can parse it as you describe above. I really don't recommend doing it this way, though. It will only end in tears. :)

Comment: @rdkrt thanks for the thought, I completely understand. I think I have to rethink the solution, as this seems to be a bit hairy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this library [dxtool](https://github.com/shiplu/dxtool/) found [here](https://github.com/shiplu).

### Login

```
require 'WebGet.php';
$w = new WebGet();
// using cache to prevent repetitive download
$w->useCache = true;
$w->cacheLocation = '/tmp';
$w->cacheMaxAge = 3600;
$w->cookieFile = '/tmp/cookie.txt';

// $login_get_data and $login_post_data is associative array
$login = $w->requestContent($login_url, $login_get_data, $login_post_data);
```

### Visiting Image containing page

```
// $image_page_url is the url of the page where your images exist.
$image_page = $w->requestContent($image_page_url);
```

### Parse images and display

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($image_page);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($imgs as $img){
    echo $img->getAttribute("src");
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this class

Comment: see comments above...I cannot specify an exact URL as it will vary depending on the id of the page passed. See above for explanation

Comment: Yes. But your url will be in a variable, isn't it? just pass the variable.

Comment: Oh, You want to login and then parse the images?

Comment: your right, I suppose I can extract the URL and place it in a variable using something like this: http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/get-current-page-url.html

Comment: see the update. Note you must know `$login_get_data`  `$login_post_data`  and `$image_page_url`.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Let me see what I can do with this.